# Strange Problem with Webservice and IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, web-services

I have a Problem which confuses me a little bit, resp. where I don't have any idea about what it could be.

The System I'm using is Windows Vista, IIS 7.0, VS2008, Windows Software Factory, Entity Framework, WCF. The Binding for all Webservices is wshttpbinding.

I'm using a Webservice hosted in IIS. This Webservice uses/calls another Webservice (also installed in the IIS). If I use a client calling the first Webservice (which calls the second Webservice) it works fine for about 4-10 Times. And then (it is repeatable to get this Problem, but sometimes it happens after 4, sometimes after 10 Time, but it always will happen), the Service and the IIS gets stuck.

Stuck means, that this Webservice isn't callable anymore and generates an timeout after 1 minute. 
Even increasing Timeout doesn't change anything.

If i try to restart the IIS I get an timeout error (and this is really confusing me. It seems that the Webservice has "crashed" somehow and blocks the Restart of the IIS). So the IIS is also "stuck" (it is not really stuck, but I can't restart it). Only if I kill the w3wp.exe IIS is restartable and the Webservice will work again (until i again call this service several times).

The logfiles (i'm no expert in things like logging or where to find/enable such logs, so to say : i'm a newbie) like http-logging, Event Viewer or WCF-Message Logging don't show any hints upon the source of the problem.

I don't have this problem when I'm using a Webservice which doesn't call another Service.
Calling a Webservice is done by Service Reference (I'm using no Proxy-Classes), but I think this should be no Problem.

I have no idea of what is happening, nor how to solve this Problem.

Regards
Rene

Edit. : I hope my posting is more readable now :-)

Comment: Paragraphs might help you get more answers - hard to read your question.  What is the code in your webservice doing?  What is the other webservice doing?  Can you post some code?

Comment: The Code queries a Database for some information. It is a simple DB-Read (done with Linq) which only returns a string. So there is nothing complex done in the Code.
I've tested it also with a little more complex code (more complex means that there are returned more data), but there I also have this problem.
The only solution-step which I could try (with my very limited knowlegde about the whole topic) is to change the binding from wshttpbinding to basichttpbinding (also I must use wshttpbinding).

Answer (score 0):

insert `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` into your web service code.  When that point is reached, you will be able to step through the service logic.  This may help you diagnose the cause of the deadlock.

Another alternative is to [turn on WCF Tracing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=wcf+tracing&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC), and diagnose that way.